# Local variable in global function

Tags: javascript

Why does it show `"AAA"` in the alert instead of `"BBB"`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4cS/

```
var z = "AAA";

function xx() {

    var z = "BBB";
    yy();

}

function yy() {

    alert(z);

}

xx();
```

Comment: This is not php nor ajax.

Comment: in PHP it happens too!!!

Comment: @amandanovaes -- This is variable scoping.

Comment: Well, in most other languages also.

Comment: @amandanovaes in php you need to use the `global` keyword to access global vars in a function

Comment: I know it's a socping issue, but any idea why? if z inside of xx is local, so when I call yy inside xx it should get the local z not the global!

Comment: Where you call the function is irrelevant - it merely alerts the value of a variable.

Comment: Kids shade your eyes from this code, if you find something like this refactor it out (remember globals are bad) and know the person who wrote this hates you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
var z = "AAA";    // 1. assign z with "AAA" as global, save it in memory address #1

function xx() {   
  var z = "BBB";  // 3. assign z with "BBB" as local, save it in memory address #2
  yy();           // 4. call function yy()
}

function yy() {   
  alert(z);       // 5. alert z from memory address #1, because i don't know the other z
}

xx();             // 2. call function xx()
```

Comment: have no idea why it is like that. It should not. but if it works like that I just have to accept and live with that.

Comment: it would be easier to understand if you try this on `C`. :)

Answer (score 0):

`var z = "BBB"` is local to the function it is declared in, aka `xx` - it shows `AAA` because `yy` has access to that variable.

Comment: but yy is being called inside xx so it should get the local variable z value.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are re-declaring the variable z inside the function

```
function xx() {

    var z = "BBB";
    yy();

}
```

The scope of z is now inside xx()

If you want to update the global var z then u should do as

```
function xx() {

     z = "BBB";
    yy();

}
```

Comment: You are right, the scope of z inside of xx is local, but when I call yy inside xx it should get the local z not the global!

Comment: @amandanovaes -- No it should not, it doesn't matter where you call the function from - it matters what is assigned to said variable.

Comment: no calling yy() inside xx() does not mean it will take z from xx() unless u pass the var as param in yy()

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4cS/1/

Here is an example of how you can get it to work, how you wanted... but this should be avoided... global variables shouldn't be accessed or set. It's considered very bad practice.

```
window.z = "AAA";

function xx() {

    window.z = "BBB";
    yy();

}

function yy() {

    alert(window.z);

}

xx();
```

---

in PHP you can do the same thing...

```
<?php

$z = "AAA";

function xx() {

    global $z;
    $z = "BBB";
    yy();

}

function yy() {

    global $z;
    echo $z;

}

xx();
```